# Replace multiple patterns inside the same boundaries in Python

Tags: python, regex

Text to search:

```
{ Field1:Value Field2:Value Field1:Value }
```

I want then, to find, and replace, each instance of Field when it equals a certain value, but only when the field lies within the { & } boundaries.

**Note:** There can be variable whitespace after the { but before the first Field. And a varying number of fields.

A regex of:

```
({\s*)(?:Field1)(:(?:.*?)})
```

Allows me to split the text into groups, allowing me to recreate new text with a different field name.

eg:

```
\1Field3\2
```

However, this will only match the **first** instance of Field1 and ignores the second, as the regex engine continues from the closing }

I thought about then using Lookbehind and Lookahead, buy Python doesn't support variable repetition for these methods, so that was out.

The "re.sub" method returns the text, altered if the regex was found/replaced, but doesn't actually say whether or not a replace was done, so I can't even loop until no matches found, unless I do a second regex to verify which doesn't feel right.

Is there any way I can do this in a single regex?

**----- EDIT -----**

I managed to distill both Emmanuel & Ωmega's solutions into what I was looking for, albeit still in multiple stages, however I think that in this case, multiple steps is the only solution.

Emmanuel's Code (working for my solution)

```
s = '{ Field1:Value Field2:Value Field1:Value } Field1:Value {Field1:Value}'
for insider in re.findall(r'{\s*Field1:.*?}', s):
    new = re.sub(r'Field1:', r'NewField:', insider)
    s = s.replace(insider, new)
```

Ωmega's Code (working for my solution)

```
def evaluate(m):
  return re.sub('Field1:', 'NewField:', m.group(0))
input = '{ Field1:Value Field2:Value Field1:Value } Field1:Value {Field1:Value}'
output = re.sub('{[^{}]*?}', evaluate, input)
```

Comment: Example output given, your given input?

Comment: I thought I'd been quite explicit already. The starting text is listed with an example of what I was looking for. Field names are variable without whitespace, values are variable text/numbers. I want to find a specific fieldname, and replace it with another. This fieldname can appear multiple times within the starting and trailing {} and variable whitespace can exist. So the output should be something like "{ NewField1:Value Field2:Value NewField1:Value }". If the name "Field1" is seen NOT inside {}, then it should remain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim's answer is really great. Mine proceeds in 2 steps:

- get all content between braces
- loop on all of them to proceed with the effective replace

This gives:

```
>>> s = '{ Field1:Value Field2:Value Field1:Value } Field4:Value {Field5:Value    }'
>>> for insider in re.findall(r'{((?:\s*Field\d+:Value\s*)*)}', s):
    new = re.sub(r'\s*Field(\d+):(\w+)\s*', r' NewField\1:\2', insider)
    s = s.replace(insider, new)

>>> s
'{ NewField1:Value NewField2:Value NewField1:Value} Field4:Value { NewField5:Value}'
```

Comment: Whilst this does way more than I needed it to do, I was able to distill it down into what I needed. Yes, it is currently a 2-step approach, but still one that works, which is more important to me than one that does it in one step. I'd prefer efficiency, but it isn't critical in this case.

Comment: My cut down version, for reference, is this: s = '{ Field1:Value Field2:Value Field1:Value } Field1:Value {Field1:Value}'
for insider in re.findall(r'{\s*Field1:.*?}', s):
    new = re.sub(r'Field1:', r'NewField:', insider)
    s = s.replace(insider, new)

Answer (score 1):

Python does support indefinite repetition in lookahead assertions. So, unless you have nested `{`/`}` structures (which *would* be impossible to handle with Python's regex engine), you can simply check whether the next brace that follows is a closing brace:

```
>>> import re
>>> subject = "{Field1:Value Field2:Value} Field3:Value {Field4:Value}"
>>> re.sub(r"Field(\d+):(\w+)(?=[^{}]*\})", r"NewField\1:\2", subject)
'{NewField1:Value NewField2:Value} Field3:Value {NewField4:Value}'
```

Comment: Whilst this certainly explained a little more to me, it doesn't solve the problem. The constraint holds for the trailing }, but makes the starting { optional. It doesn't allow for variable whitespace either.

Comment: @Psychic: As I said, this only works with unnested braces (and of course they need to be correctly balanced). Unless this is given, no Python regex can work, but if it is given, there's no need to check for the opening brace. And what exactly do you mean by "variable whitespace"?

Comment: I haven't mentioned nested braces, just a constraint that both braces must exist. I don't need nested support, but I do need to ensure that both braces are present. By variable white space, I mean that after the opening brace, there can be a variable number of spaces before the field name appears.

Comment: @Psychic: Thanks for the clarification. You would need to do the check for presence of starting braces separately, for example by checking whether your string matches `^[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)*$`. Variable whitespace isn't a problem for this regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
def evaluate(m):
  return re.sub(r'(\w+):(' + re.escape(value) + r'\b)', field + ":\\2", m.group(0))

output = re.sub(r'\{[^{}]*\}', evaluate, input)
```

See **[this demo](http://ideone.com/mDuR8f)**.

Comment: This is closer. The {} constraints appear to work. However, it's then altering it so that the output is a complete find/replace of the original text, rather than just listing the found fields.

Comment: To replace a specific field name, with a different field name, only when it appears inside {} + whitespace. From the example, change "Field1:xxxx" to, say, "NewField:xxxx", for both instances of Field1. But if I add another Field1 outside of the {} it should remain untouched.

Comment: @Psychic - Answer has been updated with new solution that should fit.